# jquery ui autocomplete with google places - force selection and remove original input while moving up down arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've following jquery ui autocomplete, that grabs data from google places...

Problem I'm having is that, once user starts going through the list of suggests via up and down arrows, original input also appears at the end. I want to remove this original input, otherwise if user hits enter form saves without forcing selection...

```
// Autocomplete location with google places API
    $("#edit_profile .location").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/words/lib/ajax.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: "autocomplete_location=1&term=" + request.term,
                cache: false,
                success: function(resp) {
                    try {
                        json = $.parseJSON(resp);
                    } catch (error) {
                        json = null;
                    }
                    //
                    if (json && json.status == "OK") {
                        //
                        response($.map(json.predictions, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.description,
                                value: item.description
                            }
                        }));
                        //
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item){
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you have any running example? i think i could have a solution, but im not sure if i get the problem

Comment: Found this workaround for problem http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nH4Nx/

Comment: @AlexKneller great! this works :) can you make this an answer, maybe with an explanation, and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your concern about disabling the default action when hitting `[Enter]` while the autocomplete menu is visible ?

If so, here is a solution : add some flag to your input, and if that flag is set, prevent the default action on keydown :

```
var $input = $('input[name="name"]');

$input.on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).data('acShown') && e.which == 13 /*enter key*/){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$input.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $input.data('acShown', true); //set the flag when showing the menu
            response(data)
        }, 300);
    },
    close: function(){
        $input.data('acShown', false); //unset the flag on close
    }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/36t7G/1/)

In the fiddle : as you can see, when the menu is shown, hitting `[Enter]` when the focus is on the input won't trigger the form submission - you will stay on the current page.

Comment: YES! my concern is exactly submitting form on ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i get the question the right way, but if i did, try "focus" method instead of the "change" method.

So the code would look like this:

```
// Autocomplete location with google places API
$("#edit_profile .location").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/words/lib/ajax.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "autocomplete_location=1&term=" + request.term,
            cache: false,
            success: function(resp) {
                try {
                    json = $.parseJSON(resp);
                } catch (error) {
                    json = null;
                }
                //
                if (json && json.status == "OK") {
                    //
                    response($.map(json.predictions, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.description,
                            value: item.description
                        }
                    }));
                    //
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item){
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not catch this with change event course it happen before, so I tried to change it to focus event but this event only fired when you select smth from suggestion list.Also I think default behavior have logic because  in case I didn't found what I want in list I would like to have option to came back and continue typing.

But anyway if you want to change this behavior you can prevent from user access to input field after the ajax return.
For example with position the suggest box over input field.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; width: 298px;">
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nH4Nx/).

Comment: This sounded like a solution, but, in reality hiding input is not a very nice workaround.